# When two neutron stars merge, does the part within the Schwartzchild radius necessarily collapse into a singularity?

Tags: black-holes

When two neutron stars merge to form a black hole, the event horizon cuts some/all of the result off from the rest of the universe, so I appreciate it's mostly speculative, but does the matter inside necessarily collapse to a point?

As soon as the horizon forms, space-time starts falling in at the speed of light, presumably making the inside larger than the outside (like the TARDIS?) and creating distance between the horizon and the... uh, core, right?

Doesn't this relieve some of the pressure, so the core can stay like a big slightly subcritical neutron star, 'pushed' further past the horizon at the speed of light as more space falls in?

Any of the outside matter that then falls in won't be able to catch up with the core to make it critical again - it even reach it!

In my mind, a black hole's inside is like someone blowing into the ant's balloon - though with the stretching all happening at the mouth of the balloon.

In case it's not obvious, I'm not a physicist. :)

Comment: You should know that the singularity (ringularity) of a black hole (rotating black hole) is an event in time, not in space. This means that things can't but move towards the singularity, just like you are moving forward in time.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux I remember that from the twisting-dimensions diagram that shows space turning into time, but those diagrams don't seem to show space-time falling in and making the inside bigger. Does the singularity destroy space-time?

Comment: @Jeanbaptiste Roux - in case of a point singularity your claim *"things can't but move towards the singularity*" is correct, but a ring singularity is repulsive everywhere except in the equatorial plane and therefore almost impossible to hit.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux “*the singularity (ringularity) of a black hole (rotating black hole) is an event in time, not in space*” - This is not exactly correct. Yes, the Schwarzschild singularity is spacelike (a moment in time), but the Kerr ring singularity is timelike (an object in space). There is however a caveat, the inner horizon. Falling from the outer to the inner horizon is like moving forward in time. So yes, you cannot escape hitting the inner horizon, but then space and time flip again, so ringularity is an object in space, except time can go in loops and you can fly to other universes.

Comment: @android.weasel Your seem to follow a common misconception that the Schwarzschild radius is spacelike (measured in meters). It is not. As follows from the metric, the Schwarzschild radius is timelike (measured in seconds). The spatial part of the Schwarzschild radius is zero meters. So there is nothing inside the Schwarzschild radius for as long as the external universe still exists. Thus your question is based on a wrong premise.

Comment: @safesphere Wow - that's comfortably freaky. I've not heard that before, though I suppose it makes sense if time and space are reversed (again, freaky!). But if the radius is zero meters inside, the thing they say about not noticing the transition if you fall into a huge black hole is wrong? You just cease to be? (And obviously the radius has spacial dimensions outside...)

Comment: @android.weasel The geometry of a curved spacetime is not intuitive. What you think is “obvious” (based on your flat space intuition) may not be true. As observed from outside, the spatial dimensions of the horizon are: the radius is zero meters (but non-zero seconds, the inner volume is zero, but the circumference is not zero. What you see also depends on where and how you move. So no, if you fall, you don’t notice the transition (because you follow the same transition yourself).